# How Hootsuite or Buffer is able to publish to LinkedIn without prompting user to refresh the authentication token?

Tags: share, linkedin-api, access-token

According to LinkedIn's documentation their authentication token lives up to 60 days only and you have to go through the whole authorisation process and get the authentication token again. But then how does Hootsuite or Buffer manages this?